# xaml How to bind to a different source?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I set `Items` in C# code like this:

```
this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = items;
```

and I've defined it in the `xaml` page like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Now I can use `Items` in a `GridView`

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="{Binding customWidth}">
                <!-- The rest-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

But the problem is that I want the inner grid use a different source:

```
this.DefaultViewModel["customWidth"] = 300;
```

How to make inner grid use a different source than its parent GridView? thanks.

Comment: You can set [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) at the instance for any `FrameworkElement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a name to your page (e.g., x:Name="myPage") and then

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="{Binding DefaultViewModel.customWidth, ElementName=myPage}">
                <!-- The rest-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

That is, you can use ElementName to go out of the current binding scope.